# How to connect mylyn to mssql bug tracking system

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, mylyn

I am using eclipse and want to use mylyn. however my bug tracking system is home made mssql based system. is there an easy way to plug it to mylyn? how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is generic SQL-connector that may work for you. Reading documentation, I wouldn't call it "easy way", but see for yourself. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Incubator/Generic_SQL_Connector

Answer (score 2):

If your bug tracking system has web based front end you might try Mylyn [Generic Web Templates Connector](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/User_Guide#Generic_Web_Templates_Connector). There you can scrap data from pretty much any web page. I believe Generic Connector is not part of the main Mylyn install - you would need to install Mylyn Extras.